# Digging up old topics by copy-paste answers

Tags: discussion

Brought into my mind today by these posts:

[Calves hurt in the front (the tibialis anterior muscle) from walking fast?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12712/calves-hurt-in-the-front-the-tibialis-anterior-muscle-from-walking-fast)

[Jogging: Tibialis anterior muscle tense up whenever I jog](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9502/jogging-tibialis-anterior-muscle-tense-up-whenever-i-jog)

[What can I do to prevent my (outer) shins from tightening while running?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12204/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-my-outer-shins-from-tightening-while-running)

I think it is fair to say they are the same question and should have been closed as duplicates. However, what do we do in this case? What is stopping me going into the archives and pulling up every single "I want to lose belly fat" question and copy-pasting an answer in there? Doing this would definitely annoy a lot of people but doesn't break any rules

Can a moderator comment?

Comment: Not sure if this is what prompted the question, but I believe I saw almost identical, old questions being dug up by the same users for giving new answers (which unfortunately weren't the best quality). Related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vote to close them as duplicates, and this will bring them back to the top of the queue. At that point, if a moderator agrees or enough others agree, then they can be closed as duplicate.

I would take a look and see which one appears to answer the question the best, and mark the others as duplicate of that one.